# Sublime text 3 Variable Explorer

Tags: ide, sublimetext3, spyder

I have searched through the whole internet and didn't find anything useful. Could please anyone suggest how to make a variable explorer in Sublime text 3 like in Spyder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If you want to create a representation of your current namespace (what is shown in the Variable Explorer), you can take a look at how we build it [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/blob/master/spyder_kernels/utils/nsview.py), specially the `value_to_display` function, the one really responsible for that.

The viewers (for lists, dicts, Numpy arrays and DataFrames) are implemented in PyQt, and you can find them [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/tree/master/spyder/plugins/variableexplorer/widgets).

To bring the value of a variable from a running IPython kernel and pass it to the viewers, we created our [own kernel](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/blob/master/spyder_kernels/console/kernel.py) that serializes a value and sends it to Spyder. In Spyder we deserialize it and pass it to the Viewers [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/plugins/variableexplorer/widgets/collectionseditor.py) (look for the `CreateEditor` method).

The process is really more complex than this little explanation, but I hope you can get an idea of how it works.